# Access DB - Submacro "Cannot Parse Expression" error

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I'm creating a form to pass parameters to a query.  I'm following the instructions located at this URL.  ["Use parameters in queries, forms, and reports"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-parameters-in-queries-forms-and-reports-8209eb5c-1589-42e2-9b20-4181f4c7a356)  I'm in step 3 (see screenshot in the article) of this article and stuck on the error in the screenshot.  I'm at a complete loss for why it's not allowing the form name as the screenshot shows.   Any assistance or direction to go would be much appreciated.[image]

Comment: Did you manually add `IsLoaded` to a VBA module? Did you perform Step 2?

Comment: Oh, I missed the `Then` in the expression. You need to remove it, it gets added automatically, as you can see on the right side.

Comment: I did that but still no go.   If you look on the right-hand side, it doesn't list my form for some reason.  Is this part of the problem?   I'm not sure why it isn't appearing there.

Comment: Is your form in design view or is it in form view?

Comment: Did you put the IsLoaded custom VBA function in a general module? If you are going to use VBA at all, why use macros? I never use dynamic parameterized queries. I use VBA to apply filter criteria to form or report object. IsLoaded is an intrinsic property of forms and reports.

Comment: I did a test of the VBA function and macro. It works without issue. I don't use macros and don't know how to open the 'In this Database' tree.

Comment: I didn't use any VBA, this was all from the macro builder.

Comment: Anyone able to tell me why the form is not listed in the Action Catalog list on the right-hand side under "In this Database"??